# Использование классов python для работы с таблицами pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Есть, к примеру такая таблица pandas, под названием sites возможно ли создать class Sites, при вызове которого после указания SiteID показывало бы строку таблицы?

```
FID  SiteID        geometry.x              geometry.y       
1    CN5544       -13627378.25            4549687.09
2    СТ5545       -13627766,2            4654587,55

a = Sites('CN5544')
a.print_info()
```

ответ был бы

```
FID SiteID  geometry.x      geometry.y      
1   CN5544  -13627378.25    4549687.09
```

Comment: можно поинтересоваться - зачем вам это? Чем не устраивает: `df.loc[df['SiteID']=='CN5544']` или `df.query("SiteID == 'CN5544'")`?

Comment: Для того, чтобы человек не знакомый с командами pandas мог просто вбить нужный сектор получить данные по нему.

Comment: Если вы пишете класс, то речь о человеке, который будет писать на Python. Не вижу смысла ограничивать его использованием вашего класса (в котором вы дадите доступ к 1/1000 от Pandas API). По-моему лучше написать функции, которые бы принимали в качестве аргумента Pandas.DataFrame и возвращали бы то что вы хотите. При этом у пользователя остается возможность пользоваться Pandas API...

Answer (score 1):

Как насчет такого примера?

```
import pandas as pd


class Sites:
    def __init__(self):
        columns = ('FID', 'SiteID', 'geometry.x', 'geometry.y')
        records = [
            (1, 'CN5544', -13627378.25, 4549687.09),
            (2, 'СТ5545', -13627766.2, 4654587.55),
        ]

        self.df = pd.DataFrame(data=records, columns=columns)

    def print_info(self, site_id=None):
        if site_id:
            filter_df = self.df[self.df['SiteID'] == site_id]
            print(filter_df)

        else:
            print(self.df)


a = Sites()
a.print_info('CN5544')
print()

a.print_info('СТ5545')
print()

a.print_info()
```

Консоль:

```
   FID  SiteID   geometry.x  geometry.y
0    1  CN5544 -13627378.25  4549687.09

   FID  SiteID  geometry.x  geometry.y
1    2  СТ5545 -13627766.2  4654587.55

   FID  SiteID   geometry.x  geometry.y
0    1  CN5544 -13627378.25  4549687.09
1    2  СТ5545 -13627766.20  4654587.55
```

Comment: Да это работает, может еще сможете подсказать, к примеру, как добраться до отдельных данных в filter_df и извлекать их и использовать в другой  функции внутри класса? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: @ЕвгенийСвентицкий, `print(filter_df['geometry.x'].values)`

Comment: спасибо, вот только ещё вопрос, а возможно, чтобы было так a = Sites('CN5544')
a.print_info()
и тогда выдавалася результат? Заранее спасибо

Comment: @ЕвгенийСвентицкий, ага, вам нужно код из `print_info` перенести в конструктор `__init__` и сразу сохранять `filter_df`, а после при вызове `print_info` вывести `filter_df`